# Alternatives to protobuf's json_format to convert protobuf message to json

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

In protobuf's python implementation, Google protobuf provides a built-in class, json_formatter to convert a protobuf message to a Dict/Json type, e.g., MessageToDict & MessageToJson

Described in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/json-formatter

The built-in method generally works well, but becomes very slow when the data gets a bit bigger.

Through the link I mentioned above, google said 'This is a simple start to get JSON formatting working. As it's reflection-based, it's not as quick as baking calls into generated messages - but is a simpler implementation. (This code is generally not heavily optimized.)'

Therefore, I wonder if there's any alternative to this that could somehow make it faster, or a 'more heavily optimized code' somewhere? Thanks

Edit: The accepted MIMETYPE for the API are application/protobuf or application/json. Wanted to improve performance on requests whose mimetype specified is application/json.

Comment: If speed is important, then why are you converting to JSON? Can you give more details about what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks! The accepted MIMETYPE for the api are application/protobuf or application/json. Wanted to improve performance on requests whose mimetype specified is application/json.

Comment: Depending on how complicated your message is, it wouldn't be too hard to write your own function to convert it into JSON. This has the obvious downside of being a pain to maintain. If your application just needs to accept JSON then perhaps its faster to parse the JSON into a protobuf and then work with it like that?

Comment: Message itself isn't very complicated. Hm ok, i will think about this. Thanks!

Comment: The slow part of using reflection is that the class needs to query itself to determine which fields it needs to write. When you write your own encoder you can skip all of those queries since you know "I need to write X, Y, and Z".